# call a webserver method from Delphi 7

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-7

I have a webserver, implemented in C#, which has a method that create a pdf file from the parameters i send to it. I want to know if it is possible to call this method and send de parameters from Delphi 7. If it is possible, what is the best way to do it?

thank you!

Comment: Does the web service use HTTP? Then you have to find out which HTTP method (GET or POST) is used to pass the parameters. Then use a HTTP component (Indy TIdHTTP) to send a parametrized request.

Comment: Is it a *web server* or a *web service*? Subtle difference.